# Why doesn't "Total Space Reserved" equal the sum of Data File space reserved and Transaction Log space reserved in the Disk Usage Report?

Tags: sql-server-2014

When running the disk usage report, it's showing the "Total space reserved" as 275 GB but the "Data Files Space Reserved" is 279 GB and the "Transaction Log Space Reserved" is 1.7 GB. Why isn't the "Total space reserved" closer to the total of "Data Files Space Reserved" + "Transaction Log Space Reserved" ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files can get out of sync.  Run DBCC UPDATEUSAGE

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-updateusage-transact-sql

> Do not run DBCC UPDATEUSAGE routinely. Because DBCC UPDATEUSAGE can take some time to run on large tables or databases, it should not be used only unless you suspect incorrect values are being returned by sp_spaceused.
>
> Consider running DBCC UPDATEUSAGE routinely (for example, weekly) only if the database undergoes frequent Data Definition Language (DDL) modifications, such as CREATE, ALTER, or DROP statements.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I have a restored copy of the DB on our Dev system which also shows the discrepancy so i'll run it and see how long it takes and if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Interesting, I ran the command on our Dev box and it ran in about 10 seconds. Command "DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (db_name)". It says it ran successfully but did not fix the report. I suppose I should create another post for this though..

Comment: As a final note: My mistake was pointed out when I posted my follow up question. The report lists the results in MB and I didn't do the conversion to GB. The report is correct after all. I did learn about the DBCC UPDATEUSAGE command though so not a total waste of time :-)